# Need a help regarding my issue

Tags: discussion, help

Some one has carelessly down voted all my questions. It is too bad to do some one at least without a comment. is there any way to know who did this or what should do not happen this again?

Comment: don't worry, that user will get penalty(may be suspension).

Comment: @Azik: Are you sure? My guess is that nothing will happen to first time downvoters.

Comment: @juergend, I've added "may be" for I'm not sure :)

Comment: If possible try not to make the title applicable to 100% of the questions on the stack exchange network

Comment: Sometimes a user will look through your profile and then vote fairly on several questions. This isnt abusive behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called *serial downvoting*. Don't worry. Every day a script automatically detects that and reverses such vote abuses.

So wait a day and if it does not get reverted then flag on of the downvoted posts for moderator attention and explain the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Suspicious voting patterns are automatically reversed (script runs daily). Specific algorithm is secret but its safe to say that if all your questions have been downvoted by the same user the votes will be reversed

Comment: Not *entirely* safe. When the question was first posted (whining on Meta has a way of attracting attention), he had only received 4–5 downvotes. There are perfectly legitimate reasons for those coming from a single user. The algorithm obviously takes into account other votes a person has cast that day, and perhaps their overall diversity of votes. The only think you can *safely* say is if the votes were *illegitimate*, they will be removed. Otherwise, hey, that's the whole point of voting.

Comment: @CodyGray That is true, but I'd be shocked if all 12 questions had been downvoted by one user and they weren't reversed. Of course Ruchi "exaggerated" a little on that point and *all* 12 weren't downvoted